# no puedo hacer funcionar el ngfor en el angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Tengo un problema con un tutorial en la web que según (y digo según, por que todo va bien hasta este momento) hace funcionar el código de angular con la directiva `ngfor`; sin embargo cuando yo lo replico parece no funcionar.
El código es bastante simple no tiene mucha ciencia, este es:

```html
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" [(ngModel)]="nombre"><br />
    <input type="text" name="apellido" [(ngModel)]="apellido"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="registrar" (click)="Register()"><br />
</form>
<br />
<p *ngIf="registered; else notregistered">{{message}} con el nombre de {{nombre}} {{apellido}}</p>
<ng-template #notregistered>
    <p>nadie registrado</p>
</ng-template>
<br />
<br />
<ul>
    <li *ngFor='let entry of entrys'>{{entry.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Y el archivo .ts es este:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
      title = 'Registro';
      message = '';
      registered = false;
      nombre:string = "";
      apellido:string = "";
      entrys: object[];

      constructor() {
        this.entrys=[
          {title:"hola1"},
          {title:"hola2"},
          {title:"hola3"},
          {title:"hola4"},
          {title:"hola5"},
          {title:"hola6"},
        ]
      }

      Register() {
        this.registered = true;
        this.message = "user registered"
      }
}
```

Es en el archivo `.html` donde me marca el error, justo hasta abajo donde esta el `{{entry.title}}` y el error que me marca Vs code es el siguiente:

```
Property 'title' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

Aquí cabe preguntarse... ¿qué esta mal?

Ps. el video del que les hablo es este https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAMX042tfhU&t=673s muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Intenta hacer esto: <ul>
<li *ngFor='let entry of entrys'>{{entry?.title}}</li>
</ul>

Comment: lo intentare deja checo... y no funciono... y a todo esto para que es el signo de interrogación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema por el que te sale`[object, object]` es por que la variables `entrys` está declarada como `object`. Lo probé quitando eso y salio lo que buscas.

Puedes ver el demo en:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vmxalt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Espero te sirva.

Comment: eso quiere decir que ya cambio o actualizaron la forma de programar el *ngfor ya que en el tutorial el tipo lo hace como en el error que tenia

Comment: todo bien y si elimino el error pero... apareció esto en el debugger 

error TS7022: 'entrys' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

Comment: @ulisesalvarez eso es otro error relacionado a Typescript que en tu caso no se a que se deba, te recomiendo hacer otra pregunta relacionado a ese nuevo error. Si mi solución te sirvió con el error del ngFor te agradecería que votes por ella.

Comment: pues la verdad si me funciono, literal yo le pongo un 10 de 10 al menos en la eliminación del error en cuanto al otro error pues es cierto ese es de typescript así que por eso no te puse una marca negativa, muchas gracias :)